# Any alternatives to IronPython, Python for .NET for accessing CLR from python?

Tags: .net, python, clr, ironpython

Are there any alternatives to Python for .NET or IronPython for accessing .NET CLR? Both of these seem to have downsides in that Python for .NET is not under active development (as far as I can tell) and you lose some features available in CPython if you use IronPython. So are there any alternatives?

Comment: It *is* under active development, they just released IronPython 2.0 a few months ago.

Comment: I said Python for .Net is not under active development, not IronPython.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from Python for .NET (which works pretty well for me), the only other solution I'm aware of is exposing the .NET libraries via COM interop, so you can use them via the pywin32 extensions.

(I don't know much about .NET com interop yet, so hopefully someone else can provide further explanation on that.)

Answer (score 1):

What feature are you missing? There is a project called [IronClad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) that is helping to open access to CPython extensions from IronPython, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you are not going to get anything more actively developed than IronPython .

IronPython is currently one of the .NET 5 being developed by the language team (C#, VB.NET, F#, IronPython and IronRuby) so I doubt that there's another open source .NET Python project that's gone anywhere near as far.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's a python derivative, but you always have [Boo](https://github.com/boo-lang/boo).